# Saving custom fields in wp_postmeta

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to save a post meta data on the database, using custom post type. The problem is I can't store the meta_key, the only one storing is the meta-value. I have two textbox there, one for event date and one for event name.. I'm trying to store the date on the meta key and the event on the value. the problem is that it only store on the meta value, and i'm not sure on the meta-key. Also how do you store multiple meta-keys and meta-values on the same post? Any idea which part of this syntax is wrong? thanks :)

```
function add_calendar_metaboxes() {
    add_meta_box('wpt_calendar_location', 'Event Date', 'wpt_calendar_location', 'calendar_holiday', 'normal', 'default');

}

// The Event Location Metabox
function wpt_calendar_location() {
    global $post;

    echo "<form method=\"POST\">";
    // Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="eventmeta_noncename" id="eventmeta_noncename" value="' .
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';
    // Get the location data if its already been entered
    $event_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_event_name', true);
    $event_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_event_date', true);

    echo '<label>Event Date</label><input type="text" name="_event_date" value="' . $event_date . '" />';
    echo '<label>Event Name</label><input type="text" name="_event_name" value="' . $event_name . '" />';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="Submit">';
    echo '</form>';

}


// Save the Metabox Data
function wpt_save_events_meta($post_id, $post) {

        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['eventmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
        return $post->ID;
        }

        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
            return $post->ID;

         $events_meta[] = array($_POST['_event_date'] => $_POST['_event_name']);

        foreach ($events_meta as $key => $value) 
        { 
            if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; 
            $value = implode(',', (array)$value);
            if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) 
            { 
                update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
            } 

            else 
            { 
                add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
            }
            if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); 
        }

}
add_action('save_post', 'wpt_save_events_meta', 1, 2);
```

Comment: I can not really understand the problem ..what do you mean it is saving only meta_value ??

Comment: Yes sir,. I think my saving function is wrong. How can I save my own meta_key and meta_value with my custom fields? I have two textbox as you can see. But I can only save one value. any idea sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you treat it like array ??

Try this simple function first

```
function wpt_save_events_meta() {
 global $post;

 update_post_meta($post->ID, "_event_date", $_POST["_event_date"]);
 update_post_meta($post->ID, "_event_name", $_POST["_event_name"]);
}
```

If this is working for you, then you can put all your validation stuff .

( IF you still find a problem, try `$post_id` instead of `$post->ID` )

**EDIT I** after comment

When you do `update_post_meta($post->ID, $_POST["_event_date"], $_POST["_event_name"] );`

You are actually saving the `_event_date` as `KEY` and the `_event_name` as `VALUE`.

Unless you specifically know what you are doing - this is wrong 
The point is to save 2 fields.

One named `"_event_date"` to hold the `dates`

One named `"_event_name"` to hold the `names`

In the case you wrote in the comments you will have something like ( I do not know the real data structure ..)

```
( post_id=1 ) 2014.03.04 => my_event_name
( post_id=2 ) 2014.03.05 => my_event_name2
( post_id=3 ) 2014.03.06 => my_event_name3
```

In the correct code you will have

```
( post_id=1 ) _event_date => 2014.03.04
              _event_name => my_event_name
( post_id=2 ) _event_date => 2014.03.05
              _event_name => my_event_name2
( post_id=3 ) _event_date => 2014.03.06
              _event_name => my_event_name3
```

You can see that in the first code , it will be really hard to actually use the data in a search for example as in the second code - it has a structure .

You should treat each form field ( meatbox field ) as an independent set of `key` % `value`  - each by it´s own.. Just try the code posted above .

Comment: I havent tried this yet, but want I need is to save the meta_key fields as event date, and meta_value field as event name. I hope you understand my point. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I understand . Just try this simple callback .

Comment: This is what I did, update_post_meta($post->ID, $_POST["_event_date"], $_POST["_event_name"] ); Is it ok if I modify the meta_key?

Comment: Oh I see,. I thought I can used the meta_key as other other,. I come up with that Idea based on the custom field on custom post where in there are name and value fields. the name is stored in meta_key and value is stored in meta_value.

Comment: Another question sir, is it possible to have multiple meta_key and meta_value on same post_id? And how can you display it on post? thanks sir

Comment: You can have as many `meta_key` and `meta_value` pairs as you wish as long as they have different `key` . otherwise you will overwrite your own data. you display it as `echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_key', true );`

Comment: So I need to modify the meta_key to have its own unique value,. like _event_date_1 so on? thanks for the info.

Comment: This is what you are doing in the `meta_box`. it will appear in each post.. and each post will be a unique event . the value you will put in the field ( _event_name for example ) , will be the `meta_value` for that post and  the `meta_key` will always be ` _event_name` for all posts . but different values.

Comment: So no need to modify the meta_key as long as the meta_value is different. Thanks for that.